# Trailing Slash on URLs rather than file name

Tags: php, html, web, slash, sites

I am trying to make a site, such as example.com/about , where the page is after the slash without the .php or .html, like example.com/about.php

I have looked online for what this is called but I couldn't find any information as I am not entirely sure what to search.

Can I do this by having folders rather than individual files, and within those files do I need an index.html?

Thank you

Comment: You are looking for "Clean URLs". To point you in the right direction, here is a link: https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-use-clean-urls/